# Confusion with qudratic equations

Tags: quadratics

According to my book

> In the given equation $$x^2+x+1=0\tag{1}$$
>
> If $a$ is a root of eqn $(1)$ then $a$ satisfies the following equation
>
> $$a^2+a+1=0\tag{2}$$
>
> $$\implies (a-1)(a^2+a+1)=0\tag{3}$$
>
> $$a^3=1$$

How do you get the last $3$ equations? Also, how does $(3)$ follow from $(2)$? It's not the same thing mathematically.

**EDIT:** Okay I've got my answer, although I still have another doubt. How do we get $a^2+a+1=0$ merely because $a$ is a root of the original equation?

Comment: Equation $(3)$ is weaker than equation $(2)$. You obtain it by multiplying $(2)$ with $(a-1)$.

Comment: It's like if $a=1\implies  a^2=1\implies a=\pm1$

Comment: Thanks. But how do we get equation(2) just because _a_ is a root of $x^2+x+1$ ? I've never come across this in all my time dealing with quadratic equation.

Comment: @Ghost, it is the *definition* of root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that $a$ is a root of $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ if $f(a)=a^2+a+1=0$. Hence equation $(2)$ follows form $(1)$, if we say that $a$ is a root. $(3)$ follows from $(2)$ since
$0=0\cdot (a-1)=(a^2+a+1)(a-1)=a^3-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $\;z=0\;$ then clearly $\,w\cdot z=0\;$ for any $\;w\;$ , right? Here it is the same, after you open up parentheses:

$$a^2+a+1=0\implies (a-1)(a^2+a+1)=0 .\;\text{But}\;\;$$

$$(a-1)(a^2+a+1)=a^3-1\implies a^3-1=0\iff a^3=1$$